# How to put animated gif or 'giffy' in imessage?

Tags: iphone

I sometimes receive imessages that contain moving images (animated gifs).

How are these imessages created? Do you need an external app or are they supported natively by imessage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways.

1. One, copy then paste from the Internet.
2. use the #images app in
   iMessage

[image: image app]

Comment: All this time it was right there. Had no idea a red magnifying glass = animated gifs!